# virtual box debian guest with nat & host-only adapters: 'No route to host' when trying to access host from guest

Tags: networking

I have just set up a Debian guest inside VirtualBox, on a Fedora host. I use two adapters: NAT (internet for the guest, which works fine) and host-only (`ssh` from host to guest, `nfs`, etc.). I am able to `ssh` from host to guest, but not the other way around. Actually, except `ping` and `traceroute`, which both give results, all other network related tools give the error: 'No route to host'.

Some information:

The host IP is 192.168.29.1.

```
axirma@dev:~$ ip addr  

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN  
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo  
inet6 ::1/128 scope host  
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000  
link/ether 08:00:27:25:1f:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0  
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe25:1f71/64 scope link  
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000  
link/ether 08:00:27:6d:16:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
inet 192.168.29.2/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global eth1  
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe6d:16e6/64 scope link  
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
axirma@dev:~$ ip route  
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  
192.168.29.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.29.2  

axirma@dev:~$ ip route get 192.168.29.1  
192.168.29.1 dev eth1  src 192.168.29.2  
    cache  ipid 0x1910 rtt 7ms rttvar 7ms cwnd 10  

axirma@dev:~$ arp  
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface  
10.0.2.2                 ether   52:54:00:12:35:02   C                     eth0  
host                     ether   0a:00:27:00:00:00   C                     eth1  

axirma@dev:~$ ping -c 4 192.168.29.1  
PING 192.168.29.1 (192.168.29.1) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 192.168.29.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.247 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.29.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.403 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.29.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.446 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.29.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.636 ms  

--- 192.168.29.1 ping statistics ---  
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.247/0.433/0.636/0.138 ms  

axirma@dev:~$ traceroute 192.169.29.1  
traceroute to 192.168.29.1 (192.168.29.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
 1  host (192.168.29.1)  0.152 ms !X  0.141 ms !X  0.143 ms !X  

axirma@dev:~$ nc -vz 192.168.29.1 22  
host [192.168.29.1] 22 (ssh) : No route to host  

axirma@dev:~$ ssh alexandru@192.168.29.1  
ssh: connect to host 192.168.29.1 port 22: No route to host
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Comment: Odd... could you try connecting to the host forcing ssh to bind to your eth1 address? The command is ssh -b 192.168.29.2 alexandru@192.168.29.1

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I have tried your suggestion and I receive the same "No route to host" result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem** is that there is a default firewall configured on the Fedora host and its set of rules ends up rejecting incoming packets from the VirtualBox host-only network interface. If we look at the rules below, we see that `icmp` packets are allowed. This is the reason why `ping` works.

```
[alexandru@the-host ~]$ sudo iptables -vL -t filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 435K  493M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   15  1559 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   20  1054 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
   51 11040 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             224.0.0.251          state NEW udp dpt:mdns
25148 1821K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 332K packets, 39M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

The possibility of a firewall crossed my mind when I saw `!X` appearing in the `tracerout` output, about which the man page says: 'communication administratively prohibited'. If we look at the firewall rules above we can see that the `traceroute` `udp` packets were reaching the last all encompassing `REJECT` rule of the `INPUT` chain.

Later, when I debugged with `nmap`:

```
axirma@the-guest:~$ nmap -Pn -T4 192.168.57.1

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-12 16:28 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.57.1
Host is up (0.95s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.57.1 are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 35.69 seconds
```

It said that all scanned ports are filtered, about which the man page says: '... means that a firewall, filter or other network obstacle is blocking the port'.

After understanding the `iptables` output it became clear that I needed to add an additional firewall rule for the desired communication to take place. **My personal solution** is the following addition to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

`-A INPUT -i vboxnet0 -j ACCEPT`, just before the all encompassing `REJECT` of the `INPUT` chain. `vboxnet0` is the host-only network interface created in VirtualBox.

Comment: I've been digging for hours trying to find the answer to the same problem, and sure enough you're right. Somebody added some pretty ridiculous firewall rules…. Thanks